# JQuery DataTables warning

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am using jquery datatables in my MVC ASP.Net application and get an alert warning while the application is running. The alert is "Warning: Scroller requires DataTables 1.10.0 or greater". I have verified that my version of DataTables is 1.10.10 and the DataTables work fairly well except for a few issues.

My issues with DataTables is when pages using it initially load, the number of rows that are supposed to be displayed do not match how many are shown. All rows are shown on a page load. Once I interact with the table, everything is fixed.

I am loading the javascript and css in my BundleConfig.cs file.

One of my views is as follows:

```
@model IEnumerable<Q5.ViewModels.ProjectVM>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Projects";
}

<h2>Projects/Deals</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover display" id="projects" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Last Updated")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Sales Person")
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "ProjectProfile", new { id = item.Id })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastUpdated)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AssignedToUserName)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#projects').DataTable();
    })
</script>
```

Comment: where's your code?  the html where the table is implemented......

Comment: @rogerdeuce I have added one of my views that use DataTables.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the table refreshed after load:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
     alert( 'DataTables has loaded.' );
     $('#example').dataTable().ajax.reload( null, false );
   }
} );
```

This may not be 100% syntax, just typed off the cuff.  I seem to remember having to do this for a project, but the details escape me.  I never could figure out why it happened so I slapped this band aid on it.

Comment: Sounds good, but I still get the warning and I wonder if the two are related.